# DataView does not return a row

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void FormView1_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e) {
    int counter = 0;
    e.Values["User_ID"] = user.Text;
    string labNumber = e.Values["Lab_Number"].ToString();
    string date = e.Values["Date"].ToString();
    string startTime = e.Values["Start_Time"].ToString();
    string endTime = e.Values["End_Time"].ToString();
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.ParseExact(startTime, "HH:mm:ss", null);
    DateTime endtime = DateTime.ParseExact(endTime, "HH:mm:ss", null);
    SqlDataSource5.SelectParameters["Lab_Number"].DefaultValue = labNumber;
    SqlDataSource5.SelectParameters["Date"].DefaultValue = date;

    for (DateTime x = currentTime; x <= endtime; x = x.AddHours(1)) {
        string time1 = x.ToString();
        string time2 = time1.Substring(time1.IndexOf(" ")+1);
        time2 = time2.TrimEnd(' ','A','M','P');
        SqlDataSource5.SelectParameters["Start_Time"].DefaultValue = time2;

        DataView dvsql = (DataView)SqlDataSource5.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        try {
            string returnEventID = (string)dvsql.Table.Rows[0][0];
            if (dvsql.Count > 0) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception f) {
            if (x == endtime) {
            }
        }
    }
    if (counter > 0) { e.Cancel = true; errorLabel.Text = "Slot is NOT available"; }
    else { errorLabel.Text = "Successfully submit the booking form!"; }
}
```

The for loop starts from a start time and goes up by one until it reaches the end time. It trims the date and the AM and PM and the select parameters are set to the trimmed value. The dataview is supposed to return a row where the Event ID can be read from.

However, it is not returning any rows to add on the counter. I checked with the test query for the SQL datasource and it is returning results so I'm quite confused. Here is the datasource in case it helps.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FCILabsDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Event_ID] FROM [Booking] WHERE (([Lab_Number] = @Lab_Number) AND ([Date] = @Date) AND ([Start_Time] = @Start_Time))">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Lab_Number" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Date" />
        <asp:Parameter DbType="Time" Name="Start_Time" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what makes the current row change in the above code? What do you get when you debug?